# Calculate genome coverage and depth from alignment

Tags: rna-seq, sequence-alignment

I have a .bam alignment file and a genome reference .fasta file. I am looking for a easy to use tool (that I can reference in a publication) to calculate the percentage coverage of the reference by the alignment and if possible also: average depth of reads that cover the gene, min/max depths. Running plot would be nice but not essential.

I wrote some python code to calculate coverage percent, but I want to reference the tool I use in a paper and dont want to mess with making a git repo and linking to it in the paper just for this simple analysis.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `samtools coverage` as explained in the [manual](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools-coverage.html) of samtoools.

Here is a example which is also described on the manual site.

```
samtools coverage -r chr1:1M-12M input.bam

#rname  startpos  endpos    numreads  covbases  coverage  meandepth  meanbaseq  meanmapq
chr1    1000000   12000000  528695    1069995   9.72723   3.50281    34.4       55.8
```

Comment: Are you sure that those statistics are the ones that make the most sense for RNASeq?

Answer (score 0):

I've used https://genome.sph.umich.edu/wiki/BamUtil before. I think this has all the functionality you want and the Devs are responsive which is nice.